# Custom divide function in python produces undesirable/wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following is my code in python that has a custom divide function. This function is to address the zero division error. However, it produces the wrong output.

## Custom divide function

```
def divide(a, b):
   return b == 0 or a/b          # If b == 0, return will be True. If false, a/b will be performed


def test():
  a = int(input('Enter a integer input 1: '))
  b = int(input('Enter a non-zero input 2: '))
  res = divide(a, b)
  
  if res == True:
     print('You have entered zero value')
  else: 
     print('Your result is %s' %res)


test()
```

When I test this function with both inputs with the same number, it returns that ' You have entered zero value'.

For instance when a = 2, b = 2, the output returns that 'you have entered zero value'

Looking for suggestions

Thanks

Comment: `1.0` happens to equal `True`.

Comment: Note that this is precisely why you should *not* overload the return value, but prefer exceptions. It is much more difficult to accidentally silence an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def divide(a, b):
   return b == 0 or a/b
```

In this function , when you give a and b as same number the evaluation becomes `False or 1` which returns value as 1. In python `1==True` returns True.

You can rewrite the line as `return False if b==0 else a/b` and check `if not res:` instead of `res==True`

Comment: The explanation in the first paragraph is correct, the proposed solution in the second not necessarily. If OP *wants* `True` when `b` is `0`, then this change is undesired.

Comment: The ``if not res:`` check would change the logic for any input that produces 0 as the actual result. For example, ``0/12`` is not a division-by-zero error but produces ``0 == False``. (While the wording of the error message is ambiguous, the check seems to be geared only for a 0 denominator.)